# How to fix clipboard problem in Amazon Linux 2 (CentOS)?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, aws, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS workstation with Linux on it and the "system" clipboard is not working so I cannot copy-paste text (ctrl+c/v etc.) between the applications running inside this workstation. I can use only the so called [primary clipboard](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/clipboard) - selecting a text and then pressing the middle mouse button.

How can I fix this?

Here's the information about the OS - afaik it's called Amazon Linux 2 but it's just a customized Centos 7

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

$ uname -r
5.15.59-33.133.amzn2.x86_64
```

I installed `xclip` to investigate this and indeed `xclip -out -selection "clipboard"` is empty if I copy from other applications running on the workstation. I tried ctrl+c, ctrl+shift+c, copy from the context menu. Also `xclip -out -selection "primary"` does contain the selections from the other windows but that's not useful.

Anyway to fix this?

*Edit:* In fact for a few applications the clipboard seems to work but for most of them it doesn't.

*Edit 2:* The applications where the clipboard is not working inside AWS Linux actually get the contents of clipboard that is in the host OS where AWS client is running. The host OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Which apps does it not work for? In terminal, the keyboard shortcut tends to be shift-ctrl-c/v

Comment: Thanks @belkarx. Copy paste works from Visual Studio, Terminal, Caja (string values), Mate Dictionary, Pluma. It doesn't work from Libre Office Writer, MS Teams, Firefox, IntelliJ Idea etc. Any idea how to debug further?

Comment: I some a similar problem about IntelliJ Idea in the past, it was related to the format in which the style of the text was stored in the clipboard and disabling that feature in IntelliJ solved the problem back then. I tried that and it didn't work... and anyway there are other apps where the clipboard doesn't work.

Comment: @GabiM are you using Wayland or X11? I faced those problems with some apps and the main reason was because I was using wayland. With X11 everything works well (in my case).

Comment: It seems I'm using X11. Thanks, @EdgarMagallon